# How can I programmatically create a private room with no admin member

Tags: element-io, matrix-org

My goal is to programmatically create a private room, invite 2 persons, and *remove the admin user from the room* – so that invitees remain fully in private.

I tried to remove admin preemptively – immediately after room is created and invites are sent, but it seems that in this case, when the only user leaves room, it automatically becomes archived or something – invitees can't join it anymore.

Second thought was to set up a listener and remove admin after someone joins room.
I followed [this guide](https://matrix.org/docs/older/usage-of-the-matrix-js-sdk/).
I created a client, subscribed to all room-related events, listed [here](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-js-sdk/blob/develop/src/%40types/event.ts), including a universal event event – an got no reaction whatsoever. I can create rooms through this client – but when room created or updated, no events triggered in client. I don't understand why.

Questions are:

1. Is it possible at all to achieve my goal?
2. If yes, what's the way to go?